# Is anyone else running into MVVM-Light Installer issues?

Tags: installation, mvvm-light

I just downloaded the MVVM light MSI. And the Installer doesn't complete and rolls back. I guess I will have to  just use the package manager.

I hope I don't break NU-GET too.

Comment: Have you seen my lost dog??? It has 4 legs ... Now, on a more serious note, can you be more specific? What are you running? Which OS? which mvvm-light MSI version? Which VS? people can't help you if you don't give them the details ... (which bring us back to how my comment began ...)